# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined firstname

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom

I am new to the angular. I am trying to do the two way data binding to read the data from the text field and adding it into the database. I couldn't able to to read the value of the customer table which is one to one relationship with the bank account table.

please don't suggest *ngIf = "bankAccount!.customer" it removed the error but i couldn't able to add anything to it.
also "?" instead of "!" both didn't worked.

When I tried to print the data in the console it is printing and also it updating the data in the database.

How to fix this error?

```js
bankAccount: Bankaccount = new Bankaccount()

  constructor(public service: BankaccountService) {
  }
async submitCreateAccountForm(createAccountForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.bankAccount?.customer)
    alert('Account Created Successfully')
    this.bankAccount = await lastValueFrom(this.service.save(this.bankAccount))
    this.bankAccount = new Bankaccount()
    createAccountForm.reset()

  }
```

```html
<div class="row m-3">
      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Customer First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname"
              [(ngModel)]="bankAccount!.customer!.firstname!"
              #firstname = "ngModel">
      </div>
     </div>
```

```
dto class
```

```
    export class Bankaccount {
  constructor(
    public actNumber?: number,
    public actType?:string,
    public actBalance?: number,
    public actCreationDate?: Date,
    public customer?:Customer
  ) {
  }
```

customer

```
export class Customer {
  constructor(
    public customer_id?: number,
    public firstname?:string,
    public lastname?:string,
    public city?:string,
    public phone?:number,
    public offers?: Offers
  ) {
  }
```